# how to rounding nested if in python

Tags: python

i've tried round fuction so many times un diffrent ways with nested if but nothing worked.

```
n=float(input("Enter your score for subject:"))
if n>=95:
    print(round(94.5),("A+"))
else:
    if n>=90 and n<=94:
        print("A")
    else:
        if n>=85 and n<=89:
            print("B+")
        else:
            if n>=80 and n<=84:
                print("B")
            else:
                if n>=75 and n<=79:
                    print("C+")
                else:
                    if n>=70 and n<=74:
                        print("C")
                    else:
                        if n>=65 and n<=69:
                            print("D+")
                        else:
                            if n>=60 and n<=64:
                                print("D")
                            else:
                                print("F")
print(round(G))
```

Comment: Welcome to SO.   Can you please clarify/explain what you're doing?  What have you tried and what errors did you get?  I'm not entirely sure where you're getting ```G``` from.

Comment: the grade don't show up and many times there is no rounding @ewong

Comment: You haven't explained what the problem is. If you're getting an unexpected result from the code, you have to give us details. What input did you enter, what result did you expect, and what result did you get instead?

Comment: Also, `G` is an undefined variable.

Comment: it's an assignment and in the instructions they give us the required output and they want us to use round function with nested if I tried hard but I didn't figure any solution.@ewong

Comment: G it's a variable and the problem is I have an assignment and in the instructions they asked to use round function with nested if function, they send the required output and I have tried in so many ways the output didn't include the grade and sometimes it came blank @JohnGordon

Comment: Give us an example of input that shows the error.

Comment: I tried 89.9 @JohnGordon

Comment: That explains it.  Your code checks for numbers between 90-94, and between 85-89.  But 89.9 is not in either of those ranges.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
n=round(float(input("Enter your score for subject:")))
if n>=95:
    print("A+")
else:
    if n>=90 and n<=94:
        print("A")
    else:
        if n>=85 and n<=89:
            print("B+")
        else:
            if n>=80 and n<=84:
                print("B")
            else:
                if n>=75 and n<=79:
                    print("C+")
                else:
                    if n>=70 and n<=74:
                        print("C")
                    else:
                        if n>=65 and n<=69:
                            print("D+")
                        else:
                            if n>=60 and n<=64:
                                print("D")
                            else:
                                print("F")
```

Comment: thanks it worked, but I don't want the rounded number in the output how could I remove it? @tntrobber123

Comment: oh, sorry just remove the "n, " out of the print statements. sorry i added them in so i could see that it was working properly.

Comment: yep! i also changed my awnser. cool!

Answer (score 1):

Others have already suggested the `round` function; a further improvement would be to make the code table-driven:

```py
GRADE_TABLE = (
    (95, "A+"),
    (90, "A"),
    (85, "B+"),
    (80, "B"),
    (75, "C+"),
    (70, "C"),
    (60, "D"),
    (0, "F"),
)

n = round(float(input("Enter your score for subject:")))

for threshold, grade in GRADE_TABLE:
    if n >= threshold:
        print(grade)
        break
```

Comment: Finally! Or a dictionary, since they maintain insertion order in Python 3.6 onwards.

Comment: Dictionary would also work, but wouldn't really match the intent here

Answer (score 1):

If you want to keep your existing code structure, I would replace all the "else if" instructions with an elif, so you don't have that creeping indentation. So:

```
n=round(float(input("Enter your score for subject:")))
if n>=95:
    print("A+")
elif n>=90 and n<=94:
    print("A")
elif n>=85 and n<=89:
    print("B+")
elif n>=80 and n<=84:
    print("B")
```

and so on.

Comment: The nesting needed to be addressed +1. Also, since each `elif` would imply being lower than the previous checks minimum, the `n<=...` check can be skipped. So just `elif n>= 90:`, `elif n>=85`, etc. The `>=85` check only occurs if it was already `<90` at the previous check.

Answer (score 0):

Only for fun, one line solution

```
n=round(float(input("Enter your score for subject:")))
l=60*["F"]+5*["D"]+5*["D+"]+5*["C"]+5*["C+"]+5*["B"]+5*["B+"]+5*["A"]+6*["A+"]
print(l[n]) #if n is between 0 and 100
```

Answer (score 0):

A variation on [Jiří Baum's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71596411/1431750), which uses an ordered list of the minimum for each grade.

**Use [`next()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#next) with a generator** to get the first grade that meets the criteria:

```py
GRADE_TABLE = (
    (95, "A+"),
    (90, "A"),
    (85, "B+"),
    (80, "B"),
    (75, "C+"),
    (70, "C"),
    (60, "D"),
    (0, "F"),
)

n = round(float(input("Enter your score for subject:")))

print(next(grade for minimum, grade in GRADE_TABLE if n >= minimum))
```

Since it's a generator expression, it's evaluated one at a time with the `if` criteria. `next` provides the first result, after which the generator isn't processed further.

Another: from Python 3.6 onwards, dictionaries maintain insertion order so the minimum score can be the keys of the dict, with the grades as values. Use `.items()` to get each `key, value` pair:

```py
GRADE_TABLE = {
    95: "A+",
    90: "A",
    85: "B+",
    80: "B",
    75: "C+",
    70: "C",
    60: "D",
    0: "F",
}

n = round(float(input("Enter your score for subject:")))

print(next(grade for minimum, grade in GRADE_TABLE.items() if n >= minimum))
```

And just for giggles, here's a two-line version which **should definitely NOT be used**:

```py
n = round(float(input("Enter your score for subject:")))
print(next(grade for minimum, grade in {95: "A+", 90: "A", 85: "B+", 80: "B", 75: "C+", 70: "C", 60: "D", 0: "F"}.items() if n >= minimum))
```